# Динамически составить скрипт в package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, package.json

Хочу составить запустить скрипт в **`package.json`** примерно таким образом:

```
npm run elint (git diff --name-only HEAD)
```

Чтобы `eslint` обрабатывал только файлы, которые вернет команда

```
git diff --name-only HEAD
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: А чем вас lint-staged (или nano-staged) не устраивают?

Comment: Если забить на винду, то `npm run eslint $(git diff --name-only HEAD)` должно работать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen надо чтобы работало именно в винде(

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо большое за подсказку nano-staged, lint-staged не работает с unstaged файлами, но nano-staged то что надо.

Comment: Хех, unstaged добавлен два часа назад :) https://twitter.com/usmanyunusov/status/1471058423378853888?s=21